# Port Forwarding Xbox Live on SonicWALL

Tags: port-forwarding

I just bought a TZ105 to get more familiar with SonicWALL products. I have an Xbox One and am I trying to port forward (get a Moderate or Open NAT).

- Services in "Xbox Live" Service Group

  - HTTP    TCP 80  80
  - DNS (Name Service) TCP    53  53
  - DNS (Name Service) UDP    53  53
  - Xbox Live (88)    UDP 88  88
  - Xbox Live (3074 TCP)  TCP 3074    3074
  - Xbox Live (3074 UDP)  UDP 3074    3074
  - Xbox Live (500 UDP)   UDP 500 500
  - Xbox Live (3544 UDP)  UDP 3544    3544
  - Xbox Live (4500 UDP) UDP 4500    4500

    `Zone    >   Zone    Priority    Source  Destination Service Action  Users`

Access Rule: `LAN   >   WAN 1   All Xbox Consoles   X1 Default Gateway  Xbox Live   Allow   All`

DHCP Reservation: `Static   IP: 192.168.168.26 for MAC (MAC Address Omitted)    X0`

Consistent NAT is enabled.

Xbox is getting the proper address, but still comes up as Strict. My SonicWALL is connected to an AT&T router.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted an access rule I didn't mean to so I reset them to default. Re-added the rule... and then NAT became Moderate? I can't really say why this worked, but I can't argue. I feel like it's been resolved, but would love to get Open NAT if possible.